# Checking flag value before inserting flag in drools

Tags: java, drools, mvel

I've produced a rule and it inserts a question in session. If the question is true, it inserts a FLAG and if the question is not true, it deletes the question and doesn't update the flag. I need to check the value of the flag before inserting the question in the session. I have tried several ways to do this but not getting the drools thing to do this. Here are my rules:
**Inserting question rule**

```
rule "Threat: ATTACK_OTHER_USERS; insert question"
agenda-group "evaluate attack category"
dialect "mvel"

when
    Threat(this == Threat.ATTACK_OTHER_USERS)
//    $FLAGS(this == FLAGS.PUBLIC_READABLE)   // i need the check here, the existing doesn't work
then

    insertLogical(QRiskFactor.QRF1_S4_PUBLIC_READABLE);
end
```

**question is true**

```
rule "Threat: Public Readable  QRF_1.4 [true]"
agenda-group "evaluate attack category"
dialect "mvel"
when
     $q1: QRiskFactor(this == QRiskFactor.QRF1_S4_PUBLIC_READABLE)
     Application($rf : riskFactors[QRiskFactor.QRF1_S4_PUBLIC_READABLE.value], $rf!.factor == "true")
then
    delete($q1);
    insert(FLAGS.PUBLIC_READABLE);

end
```

**question is false**

```
rule "Threat: Public Readable -- QRF_1.4 [not true]"
agenda-group "evaluate attack category"
dialect "mvel"
when
     $q1: QRiskFactor(this == QRiskFactor.QRF1_S4_PUBLIC_READABLE)
     Application($rf : riskFactors[QRiskFactor.QRF1_S4_PUBLIC_READABLE.value], $rf!.factor != "true")
 then
   delete($q1);

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check for the presence of your specific flag in working memory. The commented out syntax in your rule is nearly correct, except you seem to have an extraneous `$` present.

Since you've not shared what `FLAGS` is, it's a little hard to answer your question specifically. I'm going to assume, based on how you've formulated your `insert` statement, that it's an enum like this:

```
public enum FLAGS {
  PUBLIC_READABLE,
  // possibly other values
}
```

So if you want to verify that a `FLAGS.PUBLIC_READABLE` has been inserted into working memory, your rule would include:

```
when
  exists(FLAGS( this == FLAGS.PUBLIC_READABLE ))
```

I use `exists` because you've not indicated that you need to do anything with the flag, so I'm just checking for its presence.

Note that `insert` doesn't re-execute previously evaluated rules. If you need to reevaluate all of working memory, you should use `update` instead.

---

Based on comments, here is how you'd implement a simple "quiz" application. A user presents an answer to a question; if the user answers correctly, they are presented with the next question. If the user answers incorrectly, it is "game over" for them and they are given the correct answer to the question they did incorrectly.

I'm using some very simple models:

```
class Question { 
  private int id;
  private String questionText;
  private String correctAnswer;
  // getters and setters
}
class QuizUtils {
  public static Question showNextQuestion();
  public static void doGameOver(Question questionMissed);
}
```

The user's answer is a String entered directly into working memory.

```
rule "User got the question right"
when
  // the user's answer
  $userAnswer: String()
  
  // the current question
  Question( correctAnswer == $userAnswer )
then
  QuizUtils.showNextQuestion();
end

rule "User got the question wrong"
when
  $userAnswer: String
  $question: Question (correctAnswer != $userAnswer )
then
  QuizUtils.doGameOver($question);
end
```

Comment: right. I need to update the flag based on the answer to the given question to the user. and later on, I have to find the questions which were asked during the session.

Comment: so, would I be using Update or insert while adding the flag to the memory'?

Comment: THere's also an issue.FLAG.PUBLIC_READABLE is not in the memory until the question is answered. how do I deal with that? any ideas?

Comment: It's really not clear what you're doing. I've assumed a lot of things like that you're running in cloud mode which is the default. Are you actually running in stream mode?

Comment: Either update or insert will put the flag into working memory, the question of which to use boils down to if you want _all_ the rules to refire (update) or if you just want subsequent rules to now be able to key off of the flag's presence (insert).

Comment: I am new to drools. I don't know about stream mode. I am having a system which asks user a question and in response to answer, new questions are asked. I want the system to ask a single question only once. 
The flags i am talking about are needed to be used to keep track of the questions whether a question is asked or not.

Comment: if a question is not already asked, it should be displayed to the user and if it is asked, it should simply show the previous response for that session.

Comment: Yes I understand that part. But how you're intending to use drools is confusing. Your workflow describes a user interacting with your app over a period of time. Drools executes at an instance in time. Unless you're in stream mode (intended for streaming events) it's not sitting around listening for ongoing actions with a single ongoing session. You're trying to use the wrong tool for the job.